# How to tell someone (in a funny way) that you are aware that you are (too) emotive while talking about an issue?

Tags: expressions, humor, psychology, emotions

How would you tell (briefly) the person you are talking with when you are flooded with emotions —in a funny way—, that:

- you are aware of these sign, and you find it embarrassing
- you don’t take your emotion (might be frustration or passions), and
  the situation too seriously, despite what it looks like

The non funny way would be:
 - Before the discussion: I apologized in advance if I’ll be passionate
   about it, I tend to be too much passionate about these things.
 - During the discussion: I apologize, I’m aware that I’m too much
   passionate now.

(The “sorry, latin blood”, is in my opinion as shallow as absurd)

Any idea?

Comment: Don't any of these work? emotional, passionate, feeling, hot-blooded, warm, ardent, fervent, excitable, temperamental, melodramatic, tempestuous, overcharged, responsive; demonstrative, tender, loving, sentimental, sensitive. You could say **"I'm quite an *insert-word-here* person"**, perhaps.

Comment: Ne jamais se plaindre; jamais expliquer.

Comment: "Oh, has my face gone off again? Damn thing. Really need to get these leaks fixed."

Comment: "I wear my heart on my sleeve", or more casually, "I'm a drama queen"

Comment: There are many ways to tell that in a funny way. 75 ways, to be exact.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'd though less, 72 to be exact. So which are the 3 expressions I'm missing?

Comment: @JoeL. "I'm a drama queen" makes me laugh, I love it. I wish I could translate it into french!

Comment: @DanBron thanks, that's the best so far, I'll try that!

Comment: Try this. http://english.stackexchange.com/q/304679/50044

Answer (score 1):

You [wear your heart on your sleeve](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wear+heart+on+sleeve), meaning that you are very open and expressive with your feelings.

The expression has been around since at least Shakespeare:

> Othello, act 1, scene 1, line 64:
>
> Iago: For when my outward action doth demonstrate
>
> The native act and figure of my heart
>
> In compliment extern, 'tis not long after
>
> But I will **wear my heart upon my sleeve**
>
> For daws to peck at: I am not what I am.

To explain the meaning: Traditionally, the heart was thought to be the center of emotions (we have since learned it is really the prefrontal cortex of the brain, but that ruins the romance).  The sleeve is an external part of ones clothing often extended forward when greeting someone.  Thus your center of emotions is brought forward and put on display.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure that will be understood, but this story is interesting, and the effect of using that one, with the proper tone might be funny though!

Answer (score 1):

> **I'm just being facetious!**

sounds like a good expression for this.